# User grant access to access online SharePoint site. But get's no access

Tags: sharepoint-online

I had a access request from a user to gain access on our teamsite.
After i have approved the access the user still doesn't get access to the teamsite. I have even added the user to the visitor group but no luck. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can add that user using Powershell only, Don't know the root cause but its frequently happening in SharePoint Online.

You can use the Below script to add the user

```
Add-SPUser -Site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites -LoginName username@emailID.com -Group "Visitor Group"
```